# HP Vertica SQL timestamp to number

Tags: sql, vertica

I'm trying to aggregate timestamps using `STDDEV` and I keep getting the error that it doesn't exist for the argument I'm providing it. Is there a way to convert timestamps in HP Vertica SQL to a int or number format or even unix timestamp.

I've tried:

```
select a, STDDEV(timestamp1) 
from mytable 
group by a
```

I get the error no function matches the given name an argument. I've used stddev before. I looked at the actual table and saw that though it's a time stamp field it looks to be represented as a date.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a way to take the stddev of a timestamp directly.  You could maybe convert it to an epoch time, get the standard deviation, and then convert that to an interval.  It would look something like this:

```
SELECT a, STDDEV( EXTRACT( epoch FROM timestamp1 ) ) * interval '1 second'
FROM mytable
GROUP BY a
```